# Concurrent and multiple commits git access

Tags: git, github

There doesn't seem to be an obvious way for concurrent access of a single git repo. E.g., if one user wants to checkout commit A, and another commit B, the only way I can think of of doing that is having clones.

That's fine for developing, of course - each user is *expected* to have a clone - but I can't imagine that it'd work nicely when you're using a repo with a server, and want to allow users to browse different commits. You'd need roughly as many clones on the server-side as there might be users.

And yet Github does just that. How does Github do it, or how might someone else, without using a large number of clones, and preferably also without many of the IO-expensive checkout operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For browsing commits, you don't actually "check out" any particular file, you just extract objects as needed.  This works in a `--bare` repo, where there *is* no working directory (and "push"-able repos are almost all `--bare`).

To simulate this in the shell, try:

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD~3
git show HEAD~3:README          # assuming README is one of the listed files
```

If you leave out `--name-only` you'll see the raw SHA1 values for each tree-or-blob in the named commit.  A tree is a sub-directory, so:

```
git ls-tree HEAD~3 xdiff/
```

will get you the contents of the directory `xdiff`, and so on.  A blob is a file, so:

```
git cat-file -p <sha-1>
```

will get you the contents of the file (like "git show" with the appropriate path).  In fact, you can use `git show` to read the directories too:

```
git show HEAD~3:""
```

is a lot like `git ls-tree --name-only HEAD~3` (there are some minor differences, try these out to see).

(Some tree-browsers actually run git commands, some use various libraries or other direct-access-to-raw-repo methods.  Using commands is not as efficient but means you immediately adapt to new formats, such as the v4 pack file format.)

Comment: Perfect! Dealing with objects directly is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple browseable source tree, you can't do it on command line from a working directory.

But you can invoke `gitk` with:

`$ gitk --all`

to show all the branches. Then you can browse the commits and files in it. But if you're accessing it on a server through ssh, you'll need to tunnel X too.

But if you are OK with installing something that does not "default git", take a look at [GitList](http://gitlist.org/).